# Is there a limited number of columns Import-Csv can import?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to import a .csv file, change some data in it then export it back out.

The problem is the last column in the file isn't getting imported.

I've tested and found that if I delete a column, the last column does get imported. If I add another column, neither of the last two columns get imported.

It seems as though there is a  limit of 10 columns, but that would be mind-boggling and would almost certainly come up when Googling. So... what's going on here?

Here's the command I'm using. I've tried specifying the headers and that gave the same behavior as well.

```
$customers = Import-Csv .\Raw_Data\CUSTOMER.csv #-Header customer_identifier,opening_dt,closing_dt,customer_status,birth_dt,bank_emp_status,cust_seg_code,cust_coh_catgry_code,cust_coh_code,branch_identifier,as_of_date
```

The header for the file looks like this:

```
customer_identifier,opening_dt,closing_dt,customer_status,birth_dt,bank_emp_status,cust_seg_code,cust_coh_catgry_code,cust_coh_code,branch_identifier,as_of_date
```

I've also checked the newlines on the file and they are all CRLF so that shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Just created a CSV file with that header and it was fine. I even doubled it to 22 columns and it worked. I am curious to see where this goes.

Comment: @BoogaRoo How did you output it to see? I'm using Format-Table and getting the same result on my home PC.

Comment: Can we see a few data lines (sanitized of course) eith the headers as well?

Comment: Got the expected results no problem as well; no piping to any format cmdlets displays the columns in list format. What PowerShell version are you using? Are you sure your console window isn't cutting it off? can you remove the `Format-Table`?

Comment: Csv has a 32k char limit per cell and no column limit afaik

Comment: Does `(Import-Csv .\Raw_Data\CUSTOMER.csv).PSObject.Properties.Name` give you all the expected column names?

Comment: I'm outputting results by calling the variable directly. Just `$customers` outputs the data similarly to `Format-List`. Maybe the limitation is the display output from `Format-Table`?

Comment: @BoogaRoo Yep, it was Format-Table, a little googling shows it cuts off columns at the current console width *but* also seems to have a limit even if I make the console wider. Not sure but I'm past that issue... if you want to put in an answer I'll upvote and marks as answered! :)

Comment: Glad to help point in the right direction, but I'm a bit busy at the moment. I am sure this is probably a duplicate since it's hardly the first time `Format-Table` limitations have cropped up. I'll let someone else write up a quick answer or find a good duplicate target.